# Is this a valid use case for const_cast?

Tags: c++, const-cast

Imagine I have a class `Sender` that:

- takes in a message
- makes some checks to decide whether the message should be sent out or discarded
- translates the message, using a `Translator` interface
- sends out the message

Note that translating is expensive and should be avoided if the message is discarded, so translation cannot be done eagerly before passing the message to the `Sender`.

I've designed my code like this:

```cpp
class Translator {
public:
   virtual Message translate(Message inputMessage) = 0;
};

class Sender {
public:
   void send(Message message, Translator& translator) const;
}
```

Note that `translate` is not const, and `translator` is not passed by const ref to `Sender`. `Sender` doesn't care whether `translate` is const or not, it's not its problem. To be as generic as possible, `Sender` does not require `translate` to be const, as this would overly restrict implementations of `Translator`.

Now say that I want to use the Sender as follows:

```cpp
class MessageGenerator {
private:
   class NoopTranslator : public Translator {
      public:
         Message translate(Message inputMessage) override {
              return std::move(inputMessage);
         }
   } 

   NoopTranslator translator_;
   Sender sender_;

public: 
   void createMessageAndSend() const {
      Message newMessage{};
      sender_.send(std::move(newMessage), translator_);
   }
};
```

This code does not compile, because `createMessageAndSend` is declared const, so `translator_` cannot be passed as non-const reference to `Sender`. I don't want to compromise on `createMessageAndSend()` to be const. After all, there is definitely no state mutation.
I believe in this case, it is fair to do the following:

```
   void createMessageAndSend() const {
      Message newMessage{};
      sender_.send(std::move(newMessage), const_cast<Translator&>(translator_));
   }
```

Because I can confirm that `NoopTranslator` doesn't actually mutate state.

What do you think? Is there a fundamental flaw in my design, which forces me to use `const_cast` when a different approach would allow me to avoid it?

Comment: The problem is the const qualifier on createMessageAndSend. If that method can modify a member (translator) then it should not be marked const.

Comment: `void send(Message message, Translator& translator) const;` says that `translater` can be modified. Make it a const ref and you do not need to do a const_cast.

Comment: `mutable` would be a less nasty way to solve the problem but as others have said, being consistent with `const` is a better option. If a method modifies state then it's not really `const`

Comment: As used, `createMessageAndSend` should not be `const`.  But if you really want it to be `const`, it should make it's own `NoopTranslator local_translator = translator_;` for the argument used in `send`.

Answer (score -1):

Rather than `const_cast` here, I would mark `translator_` mutable. This assumes that there are some `Translator`s which are mutated when translating, otherwise it would be better to take `const Translator &` in `Sender::send`.

```
class MessageGenerator {
private:
   class NoopTranslator : public Translator {
      public:
         Message translate(Message inputMessage) override {
              return std::move(inputMessage);
         }
   } 

   mutable NoopTranslator translator_;
   Sender sender_;

public: 
   void createMessageAndSend() const {
      Message newMessage{};
      sender_.send(std::move(newMessage), translator_); // Can bind to Translator &
   }
};
```